# How to create non Django files in the static files template in a Django Project

Tags: html, django, templates, static, ide

I have a folder in my Django project called "templates", its linked to my main project which  can access the files (HTML...) correctly as I can make it display stuff like "Hello World" but the project considers the files in the folder as Django files even though when creating them I typed stuff like `main.css` or `main.html`. The issue is it doesn't tell me if I have errors and it doesn't let me auto-fill so I was wondering if there was a way to fix this.

#### Picture of my Project

[image]

Comment: At the bottom right there's a text where it says "Django txt", click on that and select HTML or CSS and that might solve your issue. It seems that a VSCode plugin causing this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask]. This question is about your IDE configuration please mention the IDE you use in the question and add the appropriate tag for the same

Comment: I rolled back your last edit because the answer doesn't belong in the question. On this site, [we maintain a strict separation between questions and answers](/tour). If you've found the solution to your own problem, that's great! Please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) in the space for an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the bottom lower right on your attached picture where it says django.txt, press it. This opens the select language mode utility function. Choose auto detect or the extension if you know it.

This automatically detects the file type and changes it to html or css; depending on the file type.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution to my issue.